# How to prevent users to download videos from lms website?

Tags: plugins, themes, video-player

I want to develop a wordpress lms website that support woocommerce payment gateways.
I've found some themes and plugins like: learnpress, wplms and much more
Some of them doesn't support uploading video in website (using third party websites like Vimeo or Youtube) and I don't want to use them.
I want my website instructors upload their video lessons in my website and other users watch them online.
The problem is all of plugins and themes that I've found doesn't prevent users to download videos.
 Please tell me is there any lms plugin or theme that prevents users from downloading the video?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this answer online which responds your question [image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem that you are going to run into is a fundamental one about how videos on websites work. To watch a video, let's say on youtube, my browser starts downloading the video and shows it to me as it does (this is called streaming) by the time I have watched the entire video, I have also downloaded it. If my browser could not download the video, it would be unable to play it to me.

Every page, image, a and anything else you view in a web browser is downloaded before you can see it.

While there are ways to stop people from keeping a copy after watching a video, there are even more ways for users to get around that. After all, your server already sent them a copy of the video so they could watch it.

The best you can hope for is to make direct video file access very hard and use a streaming-based player without any file-based cache. A sufficiently motivated user will still be able to keep a copy and there is very little you can do about it.

You may be better off finding ways to add value to the viewing on your website experience so that users feel that they would miss out if they cached the video for offline viewing.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I know that I can't stop expert users to download videos.but I want make my instructors sure that I've done what I can do to protect their videos. So please tell me is there any player that streams video with one time fee?

Comment: Maybe https://wistia.com/ would be an option for you? I know that Moz use them to deliver their Whiteboard Friday videos and there is no obvious way to download them, so it might be worth a try.